# Using WordprocessingDocument error: Unable to create mutex

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I'm using this simple pattern to create a docx file in an ASP.NET app:

```
var outputFileName = "creating some file name here...";
var outputFile = string.Format("~/App_Data/files/{0}.docx", outputFileName);

// creating a file stream to write to
var outputStream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(outputFile), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

// creating the default template
using (var sr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/some-template.docx"), Encoding.UTF8)) {
    var l = (int)sr.BaseStream.Length;
    var buffer = new byte[l];
    sr.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, l);
    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, l);
}

// creating the document parts
using (WordprocessingDocument docx = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputStream, true)) {
    // adding parts here...

    // adding a large amount of data in an iterator 
    foreach(var item in someList) {
        // adding some parts...
        outputStream.Flush();
    }

    docx.Close();
}

outputStream.Flush();
outputStream.Close();
outputStream.Dispose();
```

I have to say, the data I'm working on, is about 100,000 records from DB.

In local, it works just fine; in production server (win 2012 R2), it works fine for small files; but in large files (when there is too many records to write to file) I get this error:

> Unable to create mutex. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131464)

And here is the stack trace:

> at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Open(String infoFile, String syncName)
>      at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Lock(Boolean& locked)
>      at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
>      at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.SafeIsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, ReliableIsolatedStorageFileFolder folder)
>      at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.CreateUserScopedIsolatedStorageFileStreamWithRandomName(Int32 retryCount, String& fileName)
>      at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.SwitchModeIfNecessary()
>      at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressEmulationStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.FlushBuffer()
>      at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.RawText(Char* pSrcBegin, Char* pSrcEnd)
>      at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.RawText(String s)
>      at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteStartAttribute(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
>      at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteStartAttribute(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceName)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteAttributesTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlPartRootElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlPartRootElement.SaveToPart(OpenXmlPart openXmlPart)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlPartRootElement.Save()
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.SavePartContents()
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Dispose()
>      at MyClass.GetDocx()

**The question is:** While I'm writing the file to my own `App_Data` folder, why it's going to `IsolatedStorage`? How can I prevent that?

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465653/openxml-and-unable-to-create-mutex

Comment: @MichałKomorowski yes, I saw that (and actualy a lot of googled documents). My question is, while I'm writing the docx in my own App_Data folder, why it's going to `IsolatedStorage`? How can I prevent that? Thanks to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the stack trace you can find [SparseMemoryStream](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/MS/Internal/IO/Packaging/SparseMemoryStream.cs) class. This class under the hood uses either Memory Stream or Isolated Storage. It depends on 2 parameters called *Low Water Mark* and *High Water Mark*. If memory consumption is > than *High Water Mark* then Isolated Storage is used. As you observed it becomes a problem in the case of server side applications running on IIS. Unfortunately, the problem is that values of these parameters are hard coded in the [CompressStream](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/MS/Internal/IO/Packaging/CompressStream.cs) class. In other words it is by design.

```
 private const long _lowWaterMark = 0x19000; // we definately would like to keep everythuing under 100 KB in memory  
 private const long _highWaterMark = 0xA00000; // we would like to keep everything over 10 MB on disk
```

The author of EPPlus library had the similar [problem](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14762) and it seems to me that the solution was to use non-Microsoft packaging library.

I don't know openxml-sdk but maybe it is possible to replace a default Microsoft packaging solution with something else.

Comment: Great answer. I used to be a *deep-code-reader* as you; but it seems I'm getting old ;) Thanks to help.